# JBOSS 5: Multiple instances but jvmRoute not modified

Tags: java, jboss

I have JBoss 5 running in my machine with two configurations named `default` and `myjboss`. default configuration running with `port-default` and `myjboss` running with `port01`.

While copying default to myjboss I didnt change jvmRoute at line

```
     <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">
```

in file `/home/virt01/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/myjboss/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml`

Could somebody please explain the behavior of new instance `myjboss` as jvmRoute not mentioned to `jvmRoute=myjboss`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jvmRoute is used for load balancing purposes.

If you're using mod_cluster as your load balancer then you will not have a problem, because the mod_cluster will generate a UUID for each node that does not define a jvmRoute name. [Source (Section 6.1.5)](https://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.1.0/html/java.config.html)

If you use mod_jk instead then you must define them, because the worker nodes are defined manually and their names must match the server's jvmRoute. [Source](http://mattryall.net/blog/2006/04/load-balancing-with-tomcat-and-jk)